# Свойство PictureBox.Image не работает в событии Resize

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется такой код:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = GraphImage;
    }
```

`PictureBox`, привязан к краям формы и должен растягиваться вместе с ней. Проблема в том, что когда свойство `Image` внутри события `Resize`, пикчер бокс не меняет свои размеры при растягивании формы, всегда остается в дефолте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: а почему бы не отслеживать ресайз формы?

Comment: суть в том, что у формы нет просто события ресайза, ну его есть ресайз бегин и ресайз энд. А мне нужно чтобы картинка красиво растягивалась по мере того, как юзер растягивает форму

Comment: хотя... черт... ты натолкнул меня на мысль! можно же положить пикчер бокс на панель и использовать ресайз панели!

Comment: @WenSiL а куда оно делось-то? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Оно есть у всех контролов.

Comment: да, я ошибся, действительно есть такое у формы. я в упор не замечал. видел ресайз бегин и ресайз энд, а просто ресайз был еще ниже в другой вкладке. ну бывает, что поделать.

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать этой строкой кода в событии? Возможно, изменять масштаб изображения?

Comment: Да, но только не просто изображение, а график функции, по этому и была такая нужна пересчитывать его и постоянно перерисовывать в ресайзе.

Comment: Что делает приведённая строка кода? Имхо, она бессмысленна. Приведите более полный код. Вообще, предлагаю задать изображение не свойству `Image`, а свойству `BackgroundImage` и задать свойство `BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom` - при этом масштабирование изображения будет происходить автоматически. И не нужно обрабатывать ресайз.

Comment: Эта строка кода просто демонстрирует, что данный код не работает. Да, она бессмысленна. А почему лучше присваивать свойству BackgroundImage? На счет свойства Zoom: я про него знаю, но использовать по некоторым причинам не могу, нужно делать именно полный перерасчет при ресайзе. Сейчас проблема уже решена навешиванием кода на событие ресайз формы, а не пикчер бокса.